# Run a single container app on azure from a private docker image returns: :( Application Error

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I'm looking to use azure web apps service to run a multiple containers app, but I'm starting for the simpler case which is to run a single container for an image that it's already working as a container instance.

For now I'm doing this deployment from the web site instead of using the CLI

[image]

When I visit the site url I get this error:

[image]

From the container settings section I get this message:

```
2019-12-21 15:45:15.759 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container policy-recomd_0_31cfeac3. Elapsed time = 212.2003193 sec
2019-12-21 15:45:30.845 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container policy-recomd_0_31cfeac3. Elapsed time = 227.2867951 sec
2019-12-21 15:45:33.875 ERROR - Container policy-recomd_0_31cfeac3 for site policy-recomd did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.3163708 sec
2019-12-21 15:45:33.876 ERROR - Container policy-recomd_0_31cfeac3 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 5100, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2019-12-21 15:45:33.887 INFO  - Stoping site policy-recomd because it failed during startup.
```

**EDIT** 
This is the image menu I get for the app:

[image]

I added the port number to the configuration but still not working:

[image]

Comment: Do you solve the problem? Or need more help?

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation of the Azure Web App, it only supports to expose the port 80 and 443. You need to expose port 80 and 5100 in the Dockerfile and finally in Azure App Application Settings add two new variables, PORT=5100 and WEBSITES_PORT=80.

Comment: Where on the settings do I add those variables? I updated the question with a screenshot with the menus I see

Comment: as i said it should be in the docker file

Comment: It is in the docker file, I mean this part ou said: **d finally in Azure App Application Settings add two new variables, PORT=5100 and WEBSITES_PORT=80**

Comment: its in the configuration

Comment: No, I added that in the configuration, but still not working. I uploaded an image of that to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204662/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-luis-ramon-ramirez-rodriguez).

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy a single image to the Web App, you do not need to add the environment variable for the port which needs to expose, it will be automatically detected if you already expose the port in the Dockerfile. You can take a look at the **first** way in the [troubleshooting for NoPing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#NoPing). You can also use the second way, but it's not necessary.